# Android setError(): error message visually pointing to the wrong field

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use `setError()` to show validation errors. In one case,  the field is close to the left side of the screen, when the error message showed up, it visually pointed to the wrong `EditText` field - instead of pointing to the field showing 1234, it should really point to the blank field on the left, see attached screenshot. Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks!

The screenshot was taken on a Galaxy 3 phone running **Android 4.4.2.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one workaround, add \n to format the message and reduce the width of each line:

```
text1.setError("this field must\nbe 1 character\nin length");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your problem..
Try this..

```
EditText edt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText edt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText edt3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // Reset errors.
    edt1.setError(null);
    edt2.setError(null);
    edt3.setError(null);

    String  txt3 = edt3.getText().toString().trim();
    String  txt1 = edt1.getText().toString().trim();
    String txt2=edt2.getText().toString().trim();
    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt3)) {
        edt3.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = edt3;
        cancel = true;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt2)) {
        edt2.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = edt2;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt1)) {
                edt1.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                focusView = edt1;
                cancel = true;
            }



            if (cancel) {

                focusView.requestFocus();
            } else {

                               //do the operations you want do here

            }
```